# Calling javascript function from button hides FullCalendar in my ASP.net

Tags: javascript, asp.net, fullcalendar

I have an C# ASP.net website that is using FullCalendar (http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/).

I want to grab all the calendar events and save them to my SQL database.  I have added the following button which calls a javascript function:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

        function save() {
        alert('save');
        //this will save to database...
    }
</script>

 <asp:Button ID="btnSave" runat="server"  OnClientClick=" return save();" Text="Save" />
```

I notice that when I click the button the message appears but then the whole calendar just disappears from my page, why is this? and how can I prevent it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you're wanting to keep the page from submitting with this button. Adding `return false;` to your `save()` function will prevent the postback from occurring.  If that is not right and you have a server-side click event for this button, in it, you will need to emit the javascript needed to recreate the calendar.

Answer (score 1):

Use a HTML input button

`<input type="button" id="btnSave" runat="server" Value="save" onclick="save()" />`

Comment: A Button control does not have an AutoPostBack property.

Comment: @onskee ok sorry, have removed